# Static initializer for Python classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, static

I'm looking for an equivalent to the `static { ... }` block in Java that can be used in Python classes. Specifically, I want to be able to access static resources like the arguments of the class constructor and store them in a field of the class, like so:

```
class A:

    constructor_args = A.__init__.__code__.co_varnames

    def __init__(self, foo=0, bar=1):
        ...
```

This example doesn't work, because class A is not yet initialized when I call `A.__init__.__code__.co_varnames`.

My current workaround is to alter the static field after the class has been created like so:

```
class A:

    constructor_args = ...

    def __init__(self, foo=0, bar=1):
        ...

constructor_args = A.__init__.__code__.co_varnames
```

But this solution is rather ugly because I change a static field of a class outside of the class context and if the class contains a lot of code, it's easy to miss out on what is going on here.

So basically I need a way to call a function right after the class has been initialized, and I want to define this function inside of the class.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? A much better solution would be to define those values as class attributes, set the init defaults to None, and then only set instance variables if the parameters are actually supplied.

Comment: you are arguing that static fields are generally not useful. I disagree. As for my example code: It's really not about accessing the `co_varnames` in particular, this is just an easy problem that fails for the same reason as my actual issue.

Comment: Btw. `co_varnames` doesn't only give you the arguments but also all the variables defined in the functions body. If you want the arguments you can use `inspect.signature`.

Comment: I'm not arguing that at all. On the contrary, I'm arguing that you should define "static" (class-level) attributes explicitly, not programmatically.

Comment: So what's your solution then? I don't want to hardcode a copy of the argument list of `__init__` into a static attribute, so I'm trying to make a copy by accessing the function definition. I don't see why I shouldn't solve this programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple approach that postpones execution of code that needs the finished class by moving it inside a function defined inside the class body. To have the function called and deleted after use we define a simple decorator:

```
import inspect

def finalizing(cls):
     cls.__finalize__(cls)
     del cls.__finalize__
     return cls

@finalizing
class example:
    def __finalize__(me):
        me.constructor_args = list(inspect.signature(me.__init__).parameters)
    def __init__(self, x):
        pass

example.constructor_args
# ['self', 'x']
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to at least define the `__init__` method first, but you can access its properties immediately after:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar, baz):
        pass

    constructor_args = __init__.__code__.co_varnames
```

Inside the `class` block code executes inside its own namespace, so `__init__` is directly accessible as `__init__`.

Comment: Having said that, I'm unsure why you wouldn't simply do `Foo.__init__....` as needed…

Comment: because `Foo` cannot be accessed outside of a function until the class is constructed.

Comment: I mean in the sense that what you’re storing is just an “alias” of something that can be accessed anytime anyway.

Comment: That's true in this case. In my actual code, I'm applying a transformation to these values which I'm going to access several times so I'd like to store the result of this transformation right after the class has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [class decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/):

```
def store_constructor_args(cls):
    cls.constructor_args = cls.__init__.__code__.co_varnames
    return cls

@store_constructor_args
class A:
    def __init__(self, foo=0, bar=1):
        x = 10

print(A.constructor_args)
# ('self', 'foo', 'bar', 'x')
```

---

```
@store_constructor_args
class A:
```

is equivalent to

```
class A:
    ...
A = store_constructor_args(A)
```

Comment: that's not bad, but I still don't like that I have to define `def store_constructor_args` outside of the class context